# ios dev increasing cell content size programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to increase the size of cell image which I have set like this, in cell for row at index path delegate of table view

```
UIImageView * imgGrayCell = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];
imgGrayCell.tag = 95;
[imgGrayCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgGrayCell];
[imgGrayCell release];
```

now in some cells I have a lot of text to display, now I am facing the problem that if I increase the cell size using heightForRowAtIndexPath the size of cell image remains the same and does not increase I want to increase the size of both, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set image size dynamic and declare in .h class, when u'll increase your cell's height at the same method u can increase image height according to cell's hieght and refresh you table.

Answer (score 2):

The sort way is as following ...

Write in **CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
UIImageView * imgGrayCell = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, cell.frame.size.height)];
```

**Here dynamically at the time of creation of cell height of imageview will determine**

Comment: Thanx Dhaval, and the height of table cell i will set in height for row at index path according to the text size??